# How to install Android Studio in Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm interested in buying BQ Aquaris M10 Ubuntu Edition but first I would like to know if it's possible to install Android Studio in it.
Since the tablet comes with Ubuntu 15.04 installed and when a keyboard and a mouse are connected it turns into Ubuntu Desktop it would be great to be able to install some development apps like Android Studio but in Android webpage I couldn't find any ARM version of Android Studio.
Has anyone tried this Tablet or system and installed Android Studio in it?

Also, I've heard that it is possible to install android apks in Ubuntu Touch with some emulator. Does anyone know if it's true and how to do that?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, Android Studio has not been compiled for the ARM arch, so you won't be able to install it.

It would probably perform terribly anyway, since ARM CPUs aren't very powerful.

Comment: I've seen that the Tablet comes with GIMP pre-installed and it's an x86 version. It runs using some virtual machine of ubuntu touch so it seems that it's possible to install and run  Desktop x86 apps in ubuntu touch. I'm now trying to find out how that's made.
I'm really into that tablet. It seems a wonderfull tool to work with instead going with my heavy laptop, lol

Comment: Nope, ARM-based won't be never powerful tools and you're trying to run on Tablet with I guess 2GB RAM Android Studio which requires a lot more. With this Extra libraries would take much more. GIMP is pretty light program.